# Fonts in snap-store are not clear

Tags: ubuntu-20.04

I installed snap-store on ubuntu-20.04 and fonts in that are not clear and are like below.

[image]

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I used this command :

`‍‍sudo rm /var/cache/fontconfig/*‍‍`

`rm ~/.cache/fontconfig/*‍‍`

and no with root user :)